# google chart Json response within 1 sec but still get timeout after 30 sec and no "pause on exception"

Tags: google-visualization

I've tested this code in various constellations and only one of the constellations is giving me an error that I can't track down yet. Maybe someone else with more google-visualization experience can see the problem. In this one case, get the json resonse, then I get a token error with no token identified in the error message and "paus on error" does not pause anywhere in my js nor in external js. Then, after 30 sec. my callback is indeed called but with the error set to timeout (error in query).

## Here is the URL which you can also test without SSL

https://cio-services.eu/demoOe2/Api/Insight/GetESiteEuoChart/?viewFlag=1&eSiteKid=4b92d450-b29d-47c0-943b-00890f56caf2&periodMin=7200&keyProp=KW15

## Here is my client js which works in several scenarios

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var chartOptions = {
        curveType: 'none',
        //width: 1200,
        height: 400, 
        vAxis: { maxValue: 10, title: 'kWh/4 (15 min)' },
        hAxis: { title: 'Time' },
        title: 'Live production log',
        titlePosition: 'out',
        titleTextStyle: { fontSize: 14, textIndent: 10 },
        fontSize: 12
    };

    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    var _chart;

    function drawChart() {

        //GET GChart data           
        var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://cio-services.eu/demoOe2/Api/Insight/GetESiteEuoChart/?viewFlag=1&eSiteKid=4b92d450-b29d-47c0-943b-00890f56caf2&periodMin=7200&keyProp=KW15');

        //set query parameters
        //query.setQuery('select 1, 2');

        query.send(drawTable);
    }

    function drawTable(response) {
        //error checking
        if (response.isError()) {
            alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + '' + response.getDetailedMessage());
            return;
        }

        //convert response to JSON string
        var googleDataQuery = response.getDataTable().toJSON();

        //Convert JSON to google Data table
        var convertedData = new google.visualization.DataTable(googleDataQuery, 0.5);

        //Initialize a specific data table sub set view and store into a variable  
        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(convertedData);

        _chart.draw(view, chartOptions);
    }

    $(function () {     
        _chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Connection is being closed properly so that wasn't it :-( Same error in chrome, firefox, ie10 whereby ie10 tells me SCRIPT1004: Expected ';' GetESiteEuoChart, line 1 character 11. What?

Comment: JSFiddle: jsfiddle.net/GGleGrand/44SD9
Does google-visualization perhaps have a problem with legit use of CORS ... which I am using here. I still can't nail down the exception in the js debugger.

Comment: Looks like an eval error (with no exception thrown) so how do I get MVC WebApi formatter to add extra parens around the json (jsonp?) without creating a custom formatter. Currently using: return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, chart, "application/json");

Comment: Still same problem :-( after changing the return format and now looks like: 
"({\"version\":\"0.6\",\"reqId\":\"0\",\"status\":\"...)"
And all my console errors are gone: no exceptions, no errors, still the timeout error.

Wait! Why is my tqx=reqId%3A0 always zero here? On my local test machine it is always non zero. Something is awry. Any ideas?

Reproducible at: http://jsfiddle.net/GGleGrand/44SD9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, there is a bit of magic going on here that requires attentive reading of the doc to understand.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/implementing_data_source
JSON Response Format

### The default response format is JSON if the request includes an "X-DataSource-Auth" header, and JSONP otherwise. Note that the Google chart client actually supports a modified version of JSON and JSONP; if you are using the Java or Python helper libraries, they will put out the proper code for you; if you are parsing responses by hand, see JSON Modifications below

What happens is:

if you supply a target domain that in any way differs (even a different port) from the home domain, then google-visualization decides to remove the  "X-DataSource-Auth"  header property and thereby triggers the client to expect jsonP instead of json. Apparently the RequestID is also always zero in these cases. In any case, this means that you cannot simply reuse APIs for CORS and non-CORS access.

Just take a look at the http request header going out. If the Host: and Referer: properties differ in any way, then instead of returning pure json, you return something like this:

string returnVal = "google.visualization.Query.setResponse(" + my-valid-pure-json + ")";

Details here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/implementing_data_source?hl=en

GG